# How to host unrelated pages on WordPress domain

Tags: multisite, htaccess, directory

Is it possible to have separate pages hosted on a WordPress site?

For example, say I have my site `www.website.co.uk`, which has my WordPress blog and all that. Obviously it'll have things like `www.website.co.uk/blog/`.

What I want is to have something like `www.website.co.uk/~pages/unrelatedthing` where it would read the `.css` and `.js` files in that folder and just load them. So I could have `www.website.co.uk/~pages/unrelatedthing/index.html`. No WordPress or anything.

Basically I have a couple websites, and I don't want to pay for hosting for the lot of them but still want them accessible, so want to shove them under my still-hosted website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Just add the subdirectory and then in your `.htaccess` file (in the base directory) add, before the index.php redirect lines another redirect something like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^/otherdirectory/(.*) http://www.yourdomain.com/otherdirectory/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Just make sure you dont have any url's using `otherdirectory` in your wordpress installation.

Comment: Proposed some edits for clarity, in particular adding `/` between `^` and `otherdirectory` because without it I was getting a 'server not found' error.